# Daisy Chaining 2 HP e243i monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, hp-pavilion, daisychaining

my work sent me two new Monitors and I wanted to daisy chain them like my previous. I’m not entirely sure how to extend these monitors into one. 
Can I go VGA Monitor to monitor then display port to PC?

New monitor is HP e243i 
HDMI (HDCP)
DisplayPort (HDCP)
VGA

The thin client is a Wyse Zx0
1 DisplayPort 
1 DVI-D

Comment: Tell us what connections you actually have. There are generally several models of both monitors and computer depending on region and people shouldn't have to go hunting in order to try to help you.

Comment: @Mokubai adjusted the OP

Comment: Displayport does support Daisy Chain, but the monitor must have passthrough, otherwise it may be that with your current connections it cannot work without an active splitter or converter.

Comment: @Mokubai if I was to use a Display port MST Hub would that work? Is that essentially what you were suggesting above or do I still need to make sure pass through ?

Comment: Indeed [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-DisplayPort-Multi-Monitor-Splitter-Black/dp/B00JLRBB8I) claims it does what you want and the blurb looks like it does the right thing, three independent DP monitors from a single displayport output.